# Paste X-flipped Pose half working

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I am working on a climbing cycle and i tried to Paste X-flipped pose and it seems that my lower body of the mesh worked not the top part? I done this before for my walk cycle and it has no problem. Is there an issue im not seeing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orientation of his right arm bones is bad:

In *Edit* mode select all these bones and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>180</kbd> to rotate 180° on their axis. Then, in *Pose* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraints* > *IK*, you'll have to correct the IK *Pole Angle* -> 180°.

Or, simpler, in *Edit* mode, select all the left arm bones and go on the bottom menu bar > *Armature* > *Symmetrize*. Then, in *Pose* mode, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraints* > *IK*, you'll have to correct the IK *Pole Angle* -> 180°.

Now it works fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank You. How does that work though? do i constantly have to check that throughout my process? or was it suppose to be done earlier ?

Comment: if you simply Symmetrize it should not happen, if you have this kind of bug it generally comes from this kind of problem or bad suffix, but symmetrize precisely prevents that

Comment: So everything seems to be working but now the hands are inverted when i paste x-flipped mirrored.

Comment: what do you mean by "inverted"? keep in mind that maybe you need to rotate the IK (Pole Angle) in the Bone Constraints

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132767/paste-x-flipped-pose-half-working/132768?noredirect=1#comment228186_132768

Comment: The animation looks fine but the arms invert inward when it shifts. I changed the pole angel but it change the other pose.

Comment: perhaps share your new file

Comment: Above the comment I made

Comment: no, you just linked this page  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5931" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5931/)     My Apologies

Comment: so do exactly what I said: delete the right arm, symmetrize the left arm with the Symmetrize button, then select the IK bone which is in badly oriented (it looks like it's its left IK) and change the Pole Angle, and it works (at least on my computer)

Comment: What do you mean when IK Bone is badly orientated? DO i set my Pole angel to Zero?

Comment: in Edit mode, delete the left (or right) side of your armature, and use the Symmetrize button. Then, in Pose mode, if you see that the lower arm is twisted, you need to go in the Properties panel > Bone Constraints > IK > Pole Angle -> find the good bone angle so that it's correctly oriented

Comment: It seems to have fixed the issue. However a small problem that latched on is the right foot of the mesh is stuck on a point when i move it.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5934" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5934/)

Comment: this is another problem, you need to correct this in Weight Paint mode

Comment: I have tried that and the bone doesnt seem to want to register with the weight paint but its parented with it. Should i open up another question as it is a seperate issue?

Comment: Yes open another question   ;)